# A question about ultraweakly dense

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Let $A$ be a c*-algebra, then the positive elements in $M_{n}(A)$ are ultraweakly dense in the positive part of $M_{n}(A^{**})$.** I do not know how to prove this conclusion. Could someone show me more details.

Comment: what is  ultraweakly dense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know that $M_n(A^{**})=M_n(A)^{**}$, the matrices are playing no role here. So all you need to show is that $A_+$ is ultraweakly dense in $A^{**}_+$.